# how can i get a row text from UITable View ? or(NSIndexPath)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Can I get the row appended string from it?

If yes,tell me the way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the text out of the cells textLabel you can do so like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *text = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` to get the `UITableViewCell` that is backing a particular view.

Do note that this method will return `nil` if the row is not visible on screen. This is because **UIKit strongly encourages you to NOT keep state in views**.

Instead you should fetch the needed string from from your domain model object as needed, just as you do when you populate the table view.